# Jquery Time Value not pass and not insert in phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin

how are you

am using this code in form

```
<input class="time standard" type="text" id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['time'])? $_POST['time']:''); ?>" placeholder="Wunschuhrzeit" required/>
```

and this is working perfectly
without jquery class function (time standard is jquery class)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-clock-timepicker.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('.standard').clockTimePicker({});
                    });
                </script>
```

this is javascript code and class when i comment this script section then random value written by me goes to database easily

but with this function jquery time picker open and i select time and then i submit it then time value not pass in database

this is website link
please guide me and solve my problem

http://nailworldcenter.ch/termin.php

this is mysql code

```
echo $sql= "INSERT INTO tbappointment(  `Date` ,`Time` , `Service` ,`FName` ,`Vorname` ,`Email` ,`Phone_Number`,`Standorte` ,`Ihre_Nachricht`,`Status`  )
                 VALUES ( '".($_POST['date'])."' ,'".$_POST['time']."','".$_POST['service']."','".$_POST['name']."' ,'".$_POST['vorname']."', '".$_POST['email']."' ,'".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['branch']."' ,'".$_POST['Nachricht']."' , '".$a."' )";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

Comment: so where's the mysql/php for this?

Comment: echo $sql= "INSERT INTO tbappointment(  `Date` ,`Time` , `Service` ,`FName` ,`Vorname` ,`Email` ,`Phone_Number`,`Standorte` ,`Ihre_Nachricht`,`Status`  )
     VALUES ( '".($_POST['date'])."' ,'".$_POST['time']."','".$_POST['service']."','".$_POST['name']."' ,'".$_POST['vorname']."', '".$_POST['email']."' ,'".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['branch']."' ,'".$_POST['Nachricht']."' , '".$a."' )";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

Comment: only time value not passing..remaining all value passing easily

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score -2):

I think Your time not inserting into database due to special character.
kindly use `addslashes($_POST["time"])`

Comment: 13:12 this is time format...and when i comment script i mention above then time pass in to database with all character .. but when i enable java again then not pass

Comment: use  addslashes() method

Comment: you didn't not define value attribute in input element

Comment: <input class="time standard" type="text" id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['time'])? $_POST['time']:''); ?>" placeholder="Wunschuhrzeit" required/>

Comment: **NO**. NO. No. `addslashes` is completely inadequate, and if you think it's fine, you urgently need to read up on [how useless it is](http://www.securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/addslashes-bypass-sql-injection.html) at preventing [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).